# Using tshark to generate traffic logs every X seconds

Tags: wireshark, packet-analyzer, tshark

I'm trying to use tshark to maintain a running history of all the packets that are going through an interface, for say 30 seconds. I want it to be human readable.

This is a linux machine, and without mucking too much into the netstack source (which I can do if push comes to shove), I was wondering if I can use tshark to this.

tshark has a -b duration:10 -b files:2 which I can use to generate a rotating set of 2 files, but I don't know which format it is printing the file in or how to read it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is saving to the [pcap format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pcap), read it with tshark, wireshark, tcpdump, etc.  To read a file with tshark do a `tshark -r filename`.